# clear fields when a checkbox is unchecked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently creating a form, with a couple of physical address fields and postal address fields so if the the user fills in the physical address and the postal address is the same as the physical user needs to check the box to copy the same information, which I've done successfully however my aim is when the user un-checks the checkbox the information that's copied into the postal address must to clear/ removed. i cried to copy do a else statement and repeating the same piece of code for java and put false instead of true however its not working.

```js
function FillTextbox(f) {
  if (f.checkbox2.checked == true) {
    f.Txtbox_PA.value = f.Txtbox_Address1.value;
    f.TxtPA2.value = f.Txt_Physical2.value;
    f.TxtPA3.value = f.Txt_Physical3.value;
    f.TxtPA4.value = f.Txt_Physical4.value;
    f.TxtPA5.value = f.Txt_Physical5.value;
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label>Physical Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Txtbox_Address1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical5"><br>

  <em><b>(Check this box if Postal Address and Physical Address are the same.)</b></em>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" onclick="FillTextbox(this.form)" aria-checked="undefined" />

  <label>Postal Address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Txtbox_PA"><br>

  <input type="text" name="TxtPA2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA5"><br>

</form>
```

Comment: An `else` did work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cqg7aLnz/

Comment: Your current code only cares about the checkbox being checked `if (f.checkbox2.checked == true)`, you should write an else statement that will handle it being unchecked `(f.checkbox2.checked == false)`. In your else though, you can't reuse exactly the same code as in the if `f.TxtPA5.value = f.Txt_Physical5.value;` because that one actually fills the field with `f.Txt_Physical5.value`. Instead you should fill the field with nothing `f.TxtPA5.value = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary works well here

```js
function FillTextbox(f) {
  var checked = f.checkbox2.checked;
  f.Txtbox_PA.value = checked ? f.Txtbox_Address1.value : "";
  f.TxtPA2.value    = checked ? f.Txt_Physical2.value   : "";
  f.TxtPA3.value    = checked ? f.Txt_Physical3.value   : "";
  f.TxtPA4.value    = checked ? f.Txt_Physical4.value   : "";
  f.TxtPA5.value    = checked ? f.Txt_Physical5.value   : "";
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label>Physical Address:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Txtbox_Address1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="Txt_Physical5"><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" onclick="FillTextbox(this.form)" aria-checked="undefined" /><em><b>(Check this box if Postal Address and Physical Address are the same.)</b></em>
  <br/>

  <label>Postal Address:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="Txtbox_PA"><br>

  <input type="text" name="TxtPA2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="TxtPA5"><br>

</form>
```